# Проблемы с доменом

Tags: php

С локали переносил свой проект в сеть. Хостинг timeweb.

В проекте есть индексный файл index.php

в котором идет обращение

```
include_once('/core/models/Class_Config.php');
```

В файле конфигуратора, простейший класс:

```
 class Class_Config  {             
        public $ipBD = "127.0.0.1";
        public $NameBD = "Remont42";
        public $Admin = "admin";
        public $Pwd = "12345";
        public $Name_Theme = 'remont'; 
         ...
```

После создания объекта вызываю метод класса

```
 $ConfigConnect = new Class_Config;
 echo $ConfigConnect->Name_Theme;
```

В результате на вывод ничего не идет.
Если же в файле config.php писать `echo "что-то"`, то ответ идет от файла.
От класса ответа нету.

Судя по тому как мудрили хостеры, то я думаю, что это делали именно они, либо кто-то кто на сервере блокировки делает. Других объяснений нет, тому, почему данные не выводятся.

Второй вопрос: подскажите, куда переехать, чтобы не было таких ошибок?

Comment: Сначала откройте лог ошибок на сервере и смотрите, что вам там пишут.

Comment: А зачем хостеру что то блокировать в вашем файле ? Если тем более это не  "Вирусный файл "

Comment: вангую проблемы с путём к файлу. В `include` у вас абсолютный путь указан(от корня httpdocs) - на сервере он может не совпадать с вашим локальным

Comment: `include_once( __DIR__ . 'путь до файла');` Так вы загрузите файл относительно положения текущего файла.